# How to implement a MIDI driver for the Roland UM 4?

Tags: c++, c, windows, driver, midi

My [Roland UM4](http://www.roland.com/products/en/UM-4/) works only with 32-bit OS but it's good hardware and I think if I can get it working then I won't need to buy a new MIDI interface.

I've previously written assembler in C for an operating system but I've never written a device driver.

Could you tell whether this is a project that can be done for Windows 64 bit, and if so how it can be done? I have Visual Studio 2012 and I know C/C++ but, again, I have never written a driver before. Do I have to know x86 assembler to write the device driver or is C/C++ enough?

Comment: Are you *positive* there's no compatibility mode that can force it to run? It would be the first time I've seen a piece of equipment, MIDI no less, that wouldn't support 64bit. If not, I would buy a new interface. Some things can't be avoided and you're bound to either be forced to run old equipment, because you won't be able to support the new and improved stuff, or `byte` the bullet.

Comment: There's always the possibility of using one/more of your outs to route through some other piece of eq. that will run it.

Comment: If you cannot get the 32-bit drivers working, it would be far easier to just get a new MIDI interface, or 4 USB MIDI interfaces (and use software such as MIDI-OX to route between them if necessary).  This will add a negligible amount of latency these days.

Comment: @Brad I got a replacement MIDI interface, but still it'd be a fun project how to learn to write a driver.

Comment: Ok it was 8 years ago, but I can't beleive the dumbness of some comments. I understand more and more why the world is heading down the drain. "Buy new stuff!" is always the answer nowadays. "just get a new interface or 4?" WTH?!?! One could also have hoped that Roland, in this case, would make an updated driver for a fully working peice of hardware, but then again they want to sell new stuff instead. I'd say these comments are not helpful at all! Also the Midi protocol is over 40y ears old and works well, so why shouldn't the midi-interfaces work? It's just silly daftness!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a USB device, I would have hoped it just used the standard USB MIDI class. But then it would have worked, so I guess it doesn't. Bummer.

To implement a driver, you're going to need to reverse-engineer the USB protocol between the 32-bit driver and the hardware.

This is not super-easy (I've not done it, but I have some knowledge). You must capture the traffic, which is typically done with a [USB protocol analyzer](http://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle_usb12/), which are not cheap. I think it *can* be done with a regular PC in the middle (perhaps running Linux) but that can get kind of complicated, too.

So, the limiting factor here is probably not your programming skills per se, but rather the fact the reverse-engineering is hard.